# How to remove title and other metadata from video files?

Tags: windows-7, video, vlc-media-player, metadata

I have problem sorting videos in VLC because it is using the metadata title to sort them, but they all have the same title. Which is why I want to remove all metadata, especially titles.

How can I achieve this easiest and safest? I have over 2000 video files to process and I dont want to break them in the process.

The video files are in format .avi, .mp4, .mkv, .wmv, and more.

Comment: `ffmpeg -i in.mov -map_metadata -1 -c:v copy -c:a copy out.mov` works from the FFmpeg answer, but it creates own title. I need to remove the title completely, so it would display just the filename (not with the folder path). How could i do this?

Comment: Same problem with vlc android..

Answer (score 17):

- In Windows Explorer select all the video files you want to modify (you may want to do it in a few sets if you're dealing with 1000's of files).
- Right-click one of them and choose *Properties*.
- Slect the *Details* tab.
- Click the *Remove Properties and Personal Information* link.
- Choose what you want to remove and hit *OK*.

[image: Metadata Removal Dialogs]

Comment: In my window there is no checkboxes, but neither did "create a copy with all possible properties removed" work. No metadata was removed.

Comment: Looks like the suggested duplicate has better working answer, but it still isnt what i wanted; it creates own title from the filename, but i want to keep my filename as title.

Comment: that is great! why isn't it answer yet??? really nice solution... without any additional software.

Comment: You won't see the checkboxes if your selection includes a file that doesn't have this metadata. Try to select only mp4, wmv files to see if the checkboxes show up. I noticed that mkv and avi files don't show the checkboxes.