# Merging files doesn't work - apparently

Tags: windows-7, video-editing, merge, avi

I have 2 `.AVI` files - one 625 MB (duration 1:02:45) and the other 925 MB (duration 1:32:12). I wish to combine the files into one `.AVI` file. In a command window I issue the command:

```
copy /b *.avi combined.avi
```

`combined.avi` results with a size of 1.51 GB (which is correct) but the duration is shown as 1:02:45 and, of course, when I try to play the `combined.avi`, it finishes at 1:02:45.

Can anyone explain why I am not receiving a correctly merged file?

Comment: This is probably due to the metadata in the first .avi file. It tells the player what codec etc to use and how long the video is I think.

Comment: I would try to run `copy /b second.avi + first.avi combined.avi` see if this gets the opposite effect. (shows 1:32:12 duration) btw which version of windows are you using?

Comment: Devan:Thanks. WIndows 7. Re running second + first gives 1:32:12. Are you saying that I can't successfully merge the files?

Comment: No but I'm saying that you may need to strip out the metadata before the copy so it will create it while doing the copy Refer to [this post for removing metadata](http://superuser.com/questions/767544/how-to-remove-title-and-other-metadata-from-video-files)

Comment: I stripped out the metadata but the combined file is only 1:02:45 (using 1 + 2)

Comment: Sorry about that. So looking at [this](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd318189(v=vs.85).aspx) it looks as though part of the avi standard includes a RIFF header section on the file that specifies the length of the video much like i was suggesting before. But this will not be able to be stripped out with the instructions I provided. I think you are going to be stuck with using a video converter simliar to FFmpeg.

Comment: Devan: thanks for you help. I found Karan's solution (below) provided the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Devan mentioned in the comments above why you can't simply merge two AVIs using the *copy* command. However re-encoding shouldn't be required if both files match in terms of audio and video codecs used, resolution and so on.

Use [AviDemux](http://www.videohelp.com/software/AviDemux) or [VirtualDub](http://www.videohelp.com/software/Virtualdub) to open the first AVI and then use `File > Append` for the second.

Ensure you have **Copy** selected for both Audio and Video in AviDemux's main window (along with **AVI** as the Format):

[image]

Similarly if you're using VirtualDub ensure you have **Direct Stream Copy** selected under both the Audio and Video menus.

Comment: Karan: many thanks. AviDemux has provided the solution that  I wanted.

Comment: @PaulRichards: You're welcome!